# How do I select an element within a class with CSS?

Tags: css

Sample:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myclass">
      <span>Some text</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I select the span inside `myclass`?

Is it:

```
span.myclass {
  color: red;
}
```

It doesn't seem to get applied. If I Insect Element and set the same style it gets applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will select `span` elements within `myclass`:

```
.myclass span 
{
    color: red;
}
```

The CSS you have selects `span` elements that have the class `myclass`, e.g.:

```
<span class="myclass">Some text</span>
```

CSS selectors get evaluated right to left.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to select a span within `.myclass` then it is this:

```
.myclass span
```

What you have is looking for a span which **has** the class of `myclass`.  No such span exists so there is no effect.

Answer (score 2):

you have to do

```
.myclass span{ color:red;}
```

Which can be read "Select every span in any element with class named 'myclass'. CSS rules are evaluated right to left

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
.myclass span{ color:blue;}
```

you go in the child from the parent.